# Move files to folders in UNIX

Tags: unix

I have many files from b_in00 to b_in79, and I need to move these files to folders 00 to 79, with b_in00 going into folder 00, and so on. Could you guide me?

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
mkdir {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} 80 
for i in `seq -w 0 80`; do mv b_in${i} $i; done
```

-w means apply padding to the left such that 1 becomes 01

Alternatively:

```
mkdir {00..80}
for i in {00..80}; do mv b_in$i $i; done
```

Or even

```
for i in {00..80}; do mkdir $i; mv b_$i $i;done
```

Comment: `{00..80}` will work in both the commands that you used.

Comment: I don't want to move 00..80 to all of 00..80, and afaik it's not possible to tell 00 to move to 00 only and 01 to 01 and so on using globs like that. ...ah You meant instead of seq and as in mkdir {00..80}. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Personally, I would use a shell script.

In bash it would look like this:

```
i=0
while [[ $i -le 80 ]]
do number=$(printf %02i $i)
    mkdir $number &&
    mv b_in$number $number
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

or the single-line version

```
i=0; while [[ $i -le 80 ]]; do number=$(printf %02i $i); mkdir $number && mv b_in $number; i=$((i+1)); done
```

An alternative approach is to take all files, strip the leading b_in and use the remaining string as the directoryname:

```
for filename in b_in*
do
    dirname=${filename#b_in}
    mkdir $dirname &&
    mv $filename $dirname
done
```

Things that can go wrong and that I assume you check before you run this script:

- There are no spaces or special characters in filenames
- The directories can be created and don't conflict with existing files or directories